# Differentiation inside package

Tags: packages

I am trying to put all my functions in a single package and some of them do not work because of differentiation. Suppose I have the following package

```
BeginPackage["Diff`"] 
Diff[yy_]:=Module[{cc},cc=D[yy,x[1]];cc];
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

And suppose I do the following

```
<<Diff`
Diff[x[1]^2]
```

I expect to get 2x[1], but I get 0, what is going on? Probably I am missing something very simple. And yes I need variables in the form x[1],x[2],..., not x,y,z. Interestingly everything works perfectly fine if  I do it without packaging:

```
Diff[yy_]:=Module[{cc},cc=D[yy,x[1]];cc];
Diff[x[1]^2]
```

The last operation gives 2x[1].

Comment: `Dif[yy_, xx_] := Module[{cc}, cc = D[yy, xx]; cc];`  and then `Dif[x[1]^2, x[1]]` ?

Comment: I need to differentiate with respect to x[1],x[2],.... (many if them), I can define a list of variables and then differentiate with respect to each element, but then it is a lot of rewriting. I am just curious why I cannot differentiate with respect to smth like x[1] inside a package.

Comment: I am curious if it is impossible or I just do not know how to do it. I am new with packages.

Comment: As written, you should get `2 x[1]`, not `0`. Is what you've written your actual package code? If you are actually putting `Diff` in a `Private` context, then you would get `0`.

Comment: @SimonRochester is right, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you define `Diff` in a private context, like

```
BeginPackage["Diff`"]
Diff::usage = ""
Begin["`Private`"]
Diff[yy_] := Module[{cc}, cc = D[yy, x[1]]; cc];
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

then you will get

```
<< Diff`

Diff[x[1]^2]
(* 0 *)
```

That's because the `x` referred to in the package is in the `` Diff`Private` `` context:

```
Definition@Diff // InputForm
(* Diff[Diff`Private`yy_] := Module[{Diff`Private`cc}, 
Diff`Private`cc = D[Diff`Private`yy, Diff`Private`x[1]]; Diff`Private`cc] *)
```

and so it's not the same `x` that you are calling `Diff` with, which is in the `Global` context:

```
Context[x]
(* "Global`" *)
```

To solve this, you can declare the `x` in your package to be in the `` Diff` `` context like so:

```
BeginPackage["Diff`"]
Diff::usage = ""
x::usage = ""
Begin["`Private`"]
Diff[yy_] := Module[{cc}, cc = D[yy, x[1]]; cc];
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

Since `` Diff` `` is put on the `$ContextPath` by `EndPackage`, when you refer to `x` after loading the package, it is translated to `` Diff`x ``, which matches the definition in the package (Make sure you restart the kernel first, if you're following along):

```
<< Diff`

Diff[x[1]^2]
(* 2 x[1] *)
```